# Windows: Ensure a file is written to the physical disk

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, disk

I wrote a C++ code that writes to file and attempts to flush it to the physical disk. By the end of the code I want to know for sure that the file is written to the **physical disk** and to commit that I'm in a stable state even if someone unplugs the machine. Nevertheless, when I unplug immediately after the execution of **all** of the following lines, the file is lost i.e. it hasn't been written to the physical disk although I attempted to flush and used `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(
     filePath.c_str(),
     GENERIC_WRITE,
     0,
     NULL,
     CREATE_ALWAYS,
     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL| FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH ,
     NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
     throw MyException("CreateFile failed");
}

DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
auto errorFlag = WriteFile(
     hFile,
     data.data(),
     static_cast<DWORD>(data.size()),
     &bytesWritten,
     NULL);
if (bytesWritten != data.size() || errorFlag != TRUE)
{
     CloseHandle(hFile);
     throw MyException("WriteFile failed" + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
}

auto ret = FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
if (!ret)
{
     CloseHandle(hFile);
     throw MyException("FlushFileBuffers failed");
}

CloseHandle(hFile);

// The file isn't written to the disk yet!!!
```

How will I make sure that the file is already on the disk so I can commit the change?

Comment: That is the point of calling FlushFileBuffers().  If that did not happen then start at disabling anti-malware.  Having a closer look at the file system and disk driver are next, maybe you need to intentionally disable write caching on the disk itself.  Belongs at serverfault.com

Comment: I've seen this issue before, just with local hard disks, nothing 'exotic' like networked fileservers.  I suspect that some disk hardware is umm.. 'economical with the truth' and reports data committed to the physical medium when it's not:(

Comment: You may be better off with a server-quality drive or an SSD.

Comment: The [enable advanced performance](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vbprX.jpg) switch, in your drive properties, causes the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flag to be ignored. The cache manager will ignore the request and return the call immediately, treating it like a normal lazy write.

Comment: Folks, this code will eventually be distributed to costumers. I can't play with the entire device's properties or ship high quality drives or SSD to all of my costumers..

Comment: Try to find a good quality drive/controller combination on which your code works as intended. IMHO it looks ok and should work. When you find such a system (or several), use it to demonstrate to your customers.